# R2DBC DatabaseClient parameter binding

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I am unable to bind parameters to my query. The function looks like this:

```
override fun findVenueById(id: Long): Mono<Venue> {
    val extended = query + "WHERE v.id = :id  "
    return client
        .sql(extended)
        .bind("id", id)
        .map(venueMapper::apply)
        .one()
}
```

The client: DatabaseClient is injected from this Bean:

```
@Bean
fun databaseClient(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): DatabaseClient {
    return DatabaseClient.builder()
        .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
        .bindMarkers(BindMarkersFactory.named(":", "", 20))
        .namedParameters(true)
        .build()
}
```

When I use `.bindMarkers` with DatabaseClient builder, an exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown with message:

> Binding parameters is not supported for the statement 'SELECT v.id AS venue_id ... ... ... WHERE v.id = :0id '

Why is my parameter not supported and why it was renamed to `:0id` ?

I also tried to omit `.bindMarkers` from builder, I believe it is supposed to use a default binding strategy, but in this case an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is thrown with message:

> Cannot encode parameter of type io.r2dbc.spi.Parameters$InParameter

I went through several examples and discussions on github, but I'm unable to find a solution.

**EDIT:** I switched to 2 weeks old release org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:1.0.1.RELEASE and now it works.